# access dbpedia with spaqrl. How to get multiple actors for each movie?

Tags: wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

I want to get data of all movies present on dbpedia and list of actors associated with each movie.
I ran a query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title ?star_name
where {?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
?film_title  foaf:name ?film_name .
?film_title rdfs:comment ?film_abstract .
?film_title dbpedia-owl:starring ?star .
?star dbpprop:name ?star_name
}
```

This is giving me only first actor name. How do I get complete list of actors for each movie?

Comment: why don't you accept any answers to your questions? This behaviour discourages people to help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPedia might not hold all the actors for all the movies in it's records. In some cases only a single actor is associated with a movie, in some cases several. Your query seams to be correct although you might be getting duplicates because an actor might have several dbpprop:name properties associated with it. Alternativlly you can use the following query using subqueries:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?film_title ?star WHERE { {SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title
where {?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> } limit 10} . 
?film_title dbpedia-owl:starring ?star .
}
```